# $\arctan(x)$ as a power series for all $x \in \Bbb R$.

Tags: real-analysis, power-series, taylor-expansion

Is possible to write $\arctan(x)$ as a power series for all $x \in \Bbb R$? I mean I have found just that
$$\arctan(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}\frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}$$
but it's just for $x \in (-1,1)$.

Comment: Use $$\arctan(x)+\arctan(\frac{1}{x})=\frac{\pi}{2}$$

Comment: The Taylor series of a function, if it exists, is unique. There's no other Taylor series available (centered at zero), so if this one doesn't have an infinite radius of convergence then there's nothing you can do.

Comment: I don't think it is possible, because arctan's derivative $\frac{1}{x^2+1}$ has poles in $x=\pm i$ and the convergence radius for any power series is maximum that to it's nearest pole.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I was just wondering If I can somehow bypass it.

Comment: Maybe if you allow yourself to make a power series expansion in something else than $x$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**hint**

If $x>1$ then $0 <\frac {1}{x}<1$ and

$$\arctan (x)=\frac {\pi}{2}-\arctan (1/x) $$

and if $x <-1$ then $-1 <1/x <0$ and
$$\arctan (x)=\color {red}{-}\frac {\pi}{2}-\arctan (1/x) $$